# Get user actions in browser

Tags: javascript, php, http, web, automation

Im working on a web based project.I need to record users actions in browser (eg-things he/she clicks) .One option i found was SELENIUM IDE. But the problem is selenium only works with firefox. Is there any other good methods to do this?

Comment: You can do it with chrome as well as mentioned by Adam: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: selenium IDE can record actions in chrome? i didnt know that

Comment: yes it does and it's very good :)

Answer (score 1):

[IMacros extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) is a good alternative.

If you want to work with selenium: [Chrome Driver Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

Or [selenium RC](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

You may also take a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Comment: selenium IDE can record actions in chrome? i didnt know that..

Comment: Thankz for the nice suggestions..Any ideas of doing this from php?

Comment: I've worked with PhantomJs and CasperJs but only from JS :\, however it is very documented step by step, it is a good place to start.